# Django reset password: invalid token

Tags: django, authentication

I have deployed my Django project on production and test password reset using Django authentication

I receive an email with link but I got the message 'Invalid token' meaning that link is invalid

Settings.py

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['192.xxx.xx.xx','http://example.com/','https://example.com/'] #example.com replace by my real domain
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['example.com']
```

password_reset_email.html

```
Une demande de modification de mot de passe a été demandé par {{ email }}. 
Veuillez suivre ce lien :
{{ protocol}}://example.com{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}


PS : Merci de ne pas répondre à cet email
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True` then your URL must be in https.

You can read more about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/security/#security-recommendation-ssl).